# Resample Curve Clears Tilt

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, splines

I have a cluster of generated splines made to look like plant stalks. They are instanced on points and then I set their individual properties. In order for me to set the curve radius I have to resample the curve, but this breaks the tilt of the spline points.
If I don't resample the curve it sets the radius of all points.

Without resampling the bases point away from center, but set curve radius does not work.
[image]

With resampling tilt is incorrect but curve radius works.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my problem was I only had two control points... spline resolution doesn't affect the number of control points. I subdivided my bezier instead and that solved the problem.